# Symfyon 2 Where to place a class that gets used by multiple controller functions

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently working on a little project for myself, and I started using Symfony 2. Now everything is going pretty 'okay', but I'm really questioning myself about where to place a some sort of "main class".

The point is, I'm going to use the "same sort" of data on multiple pages / controllers. For instance I want to show a count of "posts" made by a user on page X, but also show it on page Y.

I actually want a function, lets say "getUserData($user)", that is available in multiple controllers. I do not want to use the same controller on both pages, since they are totally different besides a few parts.

Is this a helper, service or dependencyInjection? Or should I just extend the defaultcontroller of the bundle?

I have functions like this:

```
public function getPostsByUserTopic($value, $currentTopic)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $posts = $em->getRepository('DevrantStatBundle:Coffeecorner')->findBy(
        array('user' => $value,
        'topicid' => $currentTopic),
        array('time' => 'ASC')
        );

   return $posts;
}

public function getPostsByUser($value)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $posts = $em->getRepository('DevrantStatBundle:Coffeecorner')->findBy(
        array('user' => $value),
        array('time' => 'ASC')
        );

   return $posts;       
}

public function countPostsByUserTopic($value, $currentTopic)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DevrantStatBundle:Coffeecorner');
    $parameters = array(
        'user' => $value, 
        'topicid' => $currentTopic,
    );
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT COUNT( u.user ) as aantal, u.user
        FROM  DevrantStatBundle:Coffeecorner u
        WHERE u.user = :user 
        AND u.topicid = :topicid
        GROUP BY  u.user, u.topicid 
        ORDER BY  aantal DESC'
    )->setParameters($parameters);

    $count = $query->getResult();

    return $count[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a service. Services were designed specifically to provide certain functionality which needs to be applied in different parts of the system. Just create a class with functionality you need and register it as a service. Voila! :)

More on that:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: Does not really make sense for me. My function does not initiate a some sort of object that be used to do things. For example my controller passes some information like a user, type of data that should be collected and the function returns the data. I'm not going to use the object to for instance update the user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a concept like helpers in Symfony2.

For counting the posts a user made you could add a method to the user object (e.g. `getPostsCount()`) .. in the Twig-template: `{{app.user.postsCount}}`, or you could use the Twig-filter `length` : `{{app.user.posts|length}}`. But I don't know, how doctrine handles this (lazy loading? .. maybe someone can tell please?)

You could write a [Twig-Extension (a Twig-Function)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) which is actually a service in symfony, tagged with `twig.extension`. This service than gets injected the dependencies it needs (e.g. doctrine, security_context) via depency injection, defined in services.yml, services.xml or via [annotations](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle).

e.g. (Acme/FooBundle/Resources/config/services.yml):

```
acme_foo_bundle.twig.user_posts_count:
    class: Acme\FooBundle\Twig\UserPostsCount
    arguments: [@doctrine, @security_context]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

then in the template:

`{{ user_posts_count() }}`

you could do it also more generically without injecting `@security_context` to the service and passing the user to the function:

```
acme_foo_bundle.twig.user_posts_count:
    class: Acme\FooBundle\Twig\UserPostsCount
    arguments: [@doctrine]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

then in the template:

`{{ user_posts_count(app.user) }}`

you could also do it as a Twig-filter:

`{{ app.user | count_posts }}`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have edited my first message btw with some examples. Anyways I figured I should use an enitiry repository, right? Downside is, I cannot figure out why it does not generate this, but that is an other question :)

Comment: Yes. When querying the database you should do in the repository-class.